# How to Set Custom Commands in Geany

Tags: command-line, geany

I am new to Geany and i am learning how to use its features according to its manual. I got a bit stuck right here http://www.geany.org/manual/#sending-text-through-custom-commands . While i am trying to add a new custom command through Edit->Send Selection to->Set Custom Commands menu, when i "OK", the command doesn't show up. It's as it never gets saved or sth. What am i doing wrong? + Some examples on where this feature should be used would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your workflow (for 1.24 git cebc20a) should most likely be like that

1. Add
2. Inserting your command and the label for your command
3. Push another time add / Pushing enter should also work
4. OK

You could use that feature for e.g. adding some code formating tool.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you MUST enter something in the "Label" field next to the "Command" field, or Geany will ignore what  you typed in.  That is poor user interface IMHO.  It warn or ask you if you forget to enter something in the "Label" field, or use the command name as the default.  Oh well.